# trusting files on my NAS in XP

Tags: windows-xp, nas

I have a commercial Network Addressable Storage (NAS) that I use as a file storage location with multiple computers and operating systems.
I prefer to get to it by its IP address rather than set it up as a custom Windows device... which is possible, but which I do not understand, am not comfortable using, and will not use.

There are several Windows (only) executable files stored there as well, so they don't have to be on every XP computer, and I know all computers will be using the same version.

If I copy one of these executable files into a folder on my C: drive and run it from there (via a double click in windows explorer), it runs just fine.
However, if open the NAS folder containing the program in windows explorer and run it with a double click, XP gives me a dialog saying:
**"Open File - Security Warning.  The publisher can not be verified.  Are you sure you want to run this software?"**

This gets to be annoying.  It is apparent that XP has some trust issue with files on the NAS different from files on the C: drive.

**Is there any way to prevent XP from presenting me with that dialog?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `Internet Options` either through Control Panel or Internet Explorer and under the Security tab, you need to add the IP address of the nas in to the `Trusted Zones` list.

After this, click `Custom level...` and under `Launching applications and unsafe files`, change it to `Enable`.

You can also do this on the `Internet` Zone, however this is potentially dangerous as it gives pretty much everything those permissions. By doing it to the `Trusted sites` zone, we are only giving this to the sites you put in the zone.

[image]

Now this should hopefully stop the warning message.

Comment: Thank you for the very clear directions.

Unfortunately, it did not seem to solve the problem.

I tried listing it (separately) 3 different ways: //10.0.0.60, http://10.0.0.60, and https://10.0.0.60.  (I also tried back slashes, but the interface changes them to forward slashes.)
None worked, and some actually added a second dialog asking if I wanted to copy or move files from this zone.

Comment: @Mark T, I am so sorry, I left out half the steps - I have had a long week and I am not sure what happened :S Could of sworn I typed them.

Comment: Wow, great!  It finally starts programs easily.  I would have never found that on my own.  Thank you so much!

Comment: I just returned to this answer and tried it again.  It works on Windows 10 !