# Network Drive on XP/32: Opening Files w/o Extension?

Tags: windows-xp, security, windows-explorer, network-shares

Under Windows XP/32, I have configured files without an extesions, such as `README`, to be opened by:

```
C:\Programme\Emacs\bin\emacsclientw.exe -n "%1"
```

I used the guide available at the following URL:

http://www.winhelponline.com/articles/67/1/How-to-associate-Notepad-to-open-files-with-no-extension.html

Now, this works fine on local drives. However, on network drives, Windows Explorer alway gives me a warning. Something like: The file type is unknown and it may be unsafe to open it. (Original is in German)

Note that I access the share by its netbios name. And two more things:

- Opening e.g. a `.txt` file works fine. No prompt.
- The default program for opening extension-less files on the share is not EMACS, as for the local share. It is some other random text editor, "Rex".

How do I get rid of that warning?

### Update

I was able to solve the problem with files being opened in "Rex" instead of EMACS. Concerning how to properly set up associations for files without extension: Take a look at the [page on Win32 file associations](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/WThirtyTwoFileAssociations) on EmacsWiki, which I amended.

Answer (score 0):

This is nothing specific about your setup / configuration. I have copied an answer I wrote for: [Trusting files on my NAS in XP](https://superuser.com/questions/187233/trusting-files-on-my-nas-in-xp)

---

Go to `Internet Options` either through Control Panel or Internet Explorer and under the Security tab, you need to add the IP address of the nas in to the `Trusted Zones` list.

After this, click `Custom level...` and under `Launching applications and unsafe files`, change it to `Enable`.

You can also do this on the `Internet` Zone, however this is potentially dangerous as it gives pretty much everything those permissions. By doing it to the `Trusted sites` zone, we are only giving this to the sites you put in the zone.

[image]

Now this should hopefully stop the warning message.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Wil. However, so far it didn't work! I added the Internet domain name to the trusted sites. That domain name is as entered in `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`. And I changed the Security Settings as described. I also tried out security level "very Low".

Comment: Also note the details that I just added to my question.